# Graph with ordering

Tags: c++, graph, stl

I'm trying to solve this problem in a c++ code, I'd like to have not canned solutions (as boost).

Defined this --- a undirected connection. Suppose to have a graph of undetermined dimension with his indexes, stored in a container:

```
 1 - Obj1 
 2 - Obj2
 3 - Obj3
 4 - Obj4
 5 - Obj5
 ...
```

Now suppose to have:

```
   1 --- 5
   2 --- 3  
   4 --- 2
   ...
```

Now we choose to delete 3 - Obj 3 , I'd like to have:

```
1 - Obj1
2 - Obj2
3 - Obj4
4 - Obj5
...
```

and

```
1 --- 4  
3 --- 2
...
```

I'd like also to access to these objects by the indexes.
I try to find a solution but I couldn't.

What I need more to do with this elements: at first add them, with their properties stored in the objects, the same is for the connections, with no costs. After I need to delete some of them preserving references.

Which is the simplest, most efficient possible implementation, any ideas about usign STL?

Thanks!

Comment: So my scheme it's a code now!

Comment: This is by far too broad, please show some code and you'll get help for problems in it.

Comment: Don't already have a code, cause I don't have an idea to solve the problem of linking.

Comment: Please define what you want to do with them. What is the most frequent operation: adding nodes, removing nodes, adding connections, removing connections, finding/following a path, accessing a node by index, etc.? Efficiency is always a trade-off.

Comment: Ok Dark Falcon, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep things simple, just use a vector for your vertices. `V` is the type of your vertices.

```
std::vector<V> vertex;
vertex.push(Obj1);
vertex.push(Obj2);
vertex.push(Obj3);
vertex.push(Obj4);
vertex.push(Obj5);
```

You can delete a vertex by calling

```
vertex.erase(vertex.begin()+2); //delete the third entry
```

and afterwards `vertex[2]` will be `Obj4` instead of `Obj3`.

The edges of the graph are a bit more complicated. You could build a adjacency list, which is basically a 2-D vector.

```
std::vector<std::vector<V> > adjacency_list;
```

You just have to make sure, you delete the `i`th row, every entry of `i` and decrease all entries bigger than `i` by one, if you delete the `i`th vertex.

Comment: Ok for the numbering, it's the adjacency_list the problem, I have really a lot oh objects (10000 or more), I need an efficient way to scale all the references on the new order.